# Creating an object of an @Service bean, is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

i have an restful application with all the @Service,@RestController,@Repository beans. and im autowiring required beans.

Now i want to use the @service class in another class that is not managed by spring, is that possible?

These 2 classes are also in 2 diffrent maven projects if that makes any diffrence

i have tried creating a new object , as expected to no awail.
i have also tried creating diffrent constructors also to no awail.

i have googled for some anwsers but havent found any so now i turn to you experts ;)

The class i want to use!

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    ProductRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

the Restcontroller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/product")
public class ProductResource {

    @Autowired
    ProductService service;
}
```

Repo

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
}
```

Here is where i want to create the service.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String chromeDriver = args[0];
    String method = args[1];
    String domainName = args[2];
    ProductService service =  new ProductService();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);
    Runner runner = new Runner(method,domainName);
    runner.run();
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using new ProductService? In the main method are you trying to intending to get a spring managed bean of ProductService with ProductRepository injected /

Comment: Does your `main` method run in a spring project?

Comment: @Martin'sRun i guess, i want to use the methods in ProductService class to be able to use crud functions in repo.  As far as i know i need to access ProductRepository i need an ProductService object.

Comment: @Kayaman no its not a spring project

Comment: Then it has no idea about `@Autowired` or what a `@Service` is. The repository won't work, since it relies on "Spring Magic". So in short, no you won't be able to use those classes directly from your `main` method.

Comment: If the main method doesn't have a Spring context, you cant get a spring managed bean. You will have to manually create ProductRepository and set it into your ProductService object.

Comment: @Martin'sRun you can't create a repository manually, since it's an interface. This is attempting to push a square peg in a round hole, just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can instantiate a Spring-managed class in a non-Spring-managed class as long as the Spring-managed class (in this case the service) doesn't contain any Spring dependencies in it, as those will remain null (non initialized) because they are never gonna be injected by Spring.

Your service looks good to me because the ProductRepository field is not @autowired, but in your code you're creating the ProductService like this:

```
ProductService service =  new ProductService();
```

While this parameterless constructor doesn't exist in the ProductService class:

```
@Service
public class ProductService 
{
    ProductRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with a basic constructor as well and auto wire the field directly and it gives a nullpointer on the service. As far as I know if you use autowire everything connected has to be also autowired. But could be wrong there

Comment: What do you mean "auto wire the field directly"? If you want to execute it in a spring context, then the repository in the service must be an autowired field as well as the service in the controller. If you want to run it in a non spring context, there's no such thing as autowired. You need to create a new Repository (as long as the repository doesn't have any autowired fields) and then create a new Service with the repository as a parameter.

Comment: I mean not autowire the constructor but the field repository. I can't create a new Repository since it is an interface and can't be instantiated. How do you mean I should create a new Repository?

Comment: You must have a concrete implementation of the ProductRepository interface, right?

Comment: Well I only wanted to access the productservice from a non spring project so I can use the spring magic with ProjectRepository but that doesn't seem to work . So yea I guess I need a concrete implementation

Comment: You can't expect a spring dependency injection on an object that is not managed by spring. As soon as you do "new ProductService()", you can forget about spring.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible (I mean, it technically is, but it is not going to work).
To have access to your service class your second application needs to have access to the same `Spring Context`.

This is because Spring Context in your base application defines necessary dependencies that your second application doesn't have access to. One of the examples for this is `ProductRepository repository` (which is a way Spring Boot app will talk with the database), have no `Spring Context` and thus information on `DB location` and `connection URL`.

In your case you need to replicate the class and mechanism to connect to DB with DB configuration in your second project.

Comment: So I have to do the repo and db config manually? Or could I make my main method a spring application in an easy way so it has the same spring context?

Comment: Even if you make your new project a spring application, it will have separate spring context. So yes, you have to do the repo and db config manually.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to *"inject"* dependencies manually. Create a managed component that stores the reference to the ApplicationContext in a static variable, so that you can access from non-managed classes:

```java
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider  implements ApplicationContextAware  {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextProvider.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

```java
public class NoManagedClass {

    private final ManagedClass bean;

    public NoManagedClass() {
       this.bean = ApplicationContextProvider.applicationContext().getBean(ManagedClass.class);
    }
}
```

However, be aware that your non-managed objects should be created after the application context is set. You still have to start your Spring application in the main method so that the beans are initialized.

Comment: Thank you but I made a client to for the spring service instead.